# Find out if the user has just moved his mouse from a input

Tags: ajax, forms, jquery, input

I have some input fields on which I trigger a ajax function on their change() event.

The problem is that I manually trigger this event in certain situations, so it gets executed quite a lot.

SO how can I run my ajax ONLY when the user has typed something in the input and moved his cursor away from it?

Comment: With the `onblur` event? (triggers when they click off of it)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input').blur(function(){
    alert('input has lost focus'); // do ajax call here...
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Yyygr/